# How can I get exact row and column number i.e cell address by value in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get exact row and column number i.e cell address by value in Pandas dataframe? 
For example, I have the following dataframe:

```
     ClientID  LastName
0    34        Johnson
1    67        Smith
2    53        Brows
```

How can I find the cell address that has'Smith' as value?
something which returns me [1,1] as value

I know the reverse is possible eg: `df.get_value(1, 'LastName')` but note that here I also do not know the column name. I just have the key value and want to find exact cell address of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) without second and third parameetr it return positions of matched value, `[0]` is added for first match by index and by columns:

```
i, c = np.where(df == 'Smith')
val = [i[0], c[0]]
print (val)
[1, 1]
```

Comment: This does not help to search content in dataframe header.  I mean if I had to search 
``` i,c = np.where(df == 'LastName') ``` it will not work.
I am new to pandas, can you help me here?

Comment: @aayushshah - Sure, for check in columns use `i1, c1 = np.where(df.columns == 'Smith')`, I think `i1` is always same